# Program doesn't launch when while true loop is inserted?

Tags: c#, wpf, infinite-loop, freeze

I wanted to make a program that prints "Ah" if the start button is activated, I tried this:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Spam_Spammer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            while (true)
            {
                if (start.IsEnabled == false)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ah");
                }
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            start.IsEnabled = false;
            stop.IsEnabled = true;
            check.IsEnabled = false;
            spam_text.IsEnabled = false;
            endpoint.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            start.IsEnabled = true;
            stop.IsEnabled = false;
            check.IsEnabled = true;
            spam_text.IsEnabled = true;
            endpoint.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but when I launch the program, it looks like the program is launched, except the actual UI is not here? Any fixes?

[What happens when I launch it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3rm4.png)

[What it is supposed to launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf2v7.png)

Comment: The `MainWindow` constructor never completes because you put an infinite loop inside.  That's bad for a UI or any object, really.

Comment: What do you recommend then?

Comment: I recommend not using infinite loops.  Tying up a constructor is not good, nor is tying up the main thread of a GUI.  It's not clear what "if the start button is activated" means; I would guess it means clicked, but then you're checking the `IsEnabled` property.  If you want to respond to clicks and `Button_Click()` is the handler for the `Start` `Button`'s `Click` event then you should put your `WriteLine()` code in there.  If you just want to check if the `Button` is enabled then a handler for the `Window`'s `Loaded` event would be a good place for that.

Comment: Could you maybe try to reconstruct the code?? @BACON

Comment: I couldn't do that, no.  Perhaps someone else would like to.

Comment: `That's bad` is an understatement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window isn't opening properly because it never leaves its constructor. You can run the code as a `Task` from the button click so it doesn't block the UI thread.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static volatile bool running = false;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (running)
            return;

        running = true;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (running)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Running");
            }
        });
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Note that `Task.Run()` returns almost immediately (hence letting the calling method finish) but the Task itself will continue running. This way you don't have to completely disable UI elements either.

[Task.Run docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)